# Standard directory structure in Gradle mixing languages

Tags: java, gradle, directory

In my project I am building Java desktop application but have a bunch of c++ header files and xml bindings used to generate additional Java source files. I would like to follow the convention as for placing them in my directory source tree properly.

```
└── src
    ├── main
    │    └── java
    │         └── JavaClass.java
    └── test
```

I did some analysis and it seems that `src/main`, `src/test` are places where Java alike plugins looks for the sources (Java,Groovy,Scala,Closure).

I've seen that cpp/c files in Gradle plugin are stored outside of main/test dirs.

What do you recommend ? To create a subdirectory in `main` or move my additional stuff outside.

Second question, should I mix generated Java sources with the normal ones ? As for now I am keeping them in separate directory and compile all of Java sources to one single jar then.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend picking the normal Gradle/Maven directory structure (src/{type}/{language}) and add an extra 'type' for the generated sources. So I would lay out the project like:

```
└── src
    ├── generatedMain
    │    └── java
    ├── main
    │    ├── java
    │    ├── scala
    │    ├── resources
    │    └── <language>
    └── test
         ├── java
         ├── scala
         ├── resources
         └── <language>
```